# Data in text file, like a matrix, with string and number. I want to set a filter, to change some Strings based condition of number by python

Tags: python, text-files

For example:

```
300 "FTPAT1  2   " 301 "CHURCH  2   " "01" "Open"   "Line"     
300 "CHURCH  2   " 301 "GREENL1 1   " "01" "Open"   "Line"      
400 "FTPAT1  2   " 401 "CHURCH  2   " "01" "Closed" "Line"     
400 "CHURCH  2   " 401 "GREENL1 1   " "01" "Closed" "Line"
```

I want to change the 300-301, "open" to "Closed", and
change the 400-401, "closed" to "Open".

So far, what I am doing is:

```
file = open('testfile.txt', 'r'):
for line in file: 
    print line,
```

Please help me! 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
with open('filename.txt') as f:
   with open('new_filename.txt', 'w') as f1:
     f1.write(re.sub('Open|Closed', '{}', f.read()).format(*['Open' if i == 'Closed' else 'Closed' for i in re.findall('Open|Closed', f.read())]))
```

Output:

```
300 "FTPAT1 2 " 301 "CHURCH 2 " "01" "Closed" "Line"
300 "CHURCH 2 " 301 "GREENL1 1 " "01" "Closed" "Line"
400 "FTPAT1 2 " 401 "CHURCH 2 " "01" "Open" "Line"
400 "CHURCH 2 " 401 "GREENL1 1 " "01" "Open" "Line"
```